# Linux/ALSA: Callback when frame is written to sound card

Tags: c++, linux, alsa

I'm new to sound programming and ALSA. I'd like to create a little application, that for example prints out to the console when a frame of data is written to ALSA with `snd_pcm_writei(...)`. Is that possible and if so, how?
Currently I'm thinking of registering a callback to ALSA so when an application calls `snd_pcm_writei(...)` the callback is executed. But I'm not sure that is how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use

- *blocking mode* (the default), in which `snd_pcm_write*()` returns only when all the data has been written into the ring buffer (or when an error has occured), or
- *non-blocking mode* (enabled with `SND_PCM_NONBLOCK` when opening, or `snd_pcm_nonblock()`), in which you can use `poll()`/`epoll()` etc. to get a notification.

Using an ALSA async handler works only with certain devices, and has all the drawbacks of signal handlers; it is deprecated.